# Put G+ back on share menu?

Tags: google-plus, share-menu

It use to be when I went to share a photo on from my Droid, a little menu would pop up with Facebook, G+, GMail, text messages, and more.

After what I think was an update, that menu changed.  G+ seems to have been removed and something called "Photos" has replaced it.  Tapping "More" lists a lot more apps but none of them are G+.

Choosing photos does not create a post on my G+ stream.  Instead it uploads the photo to some weird holding place that can only be accessed from the G+ web interface.

How can I get my G+ app back into the share menu?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have tried Andmade Share. It involves way too many taps.  First after tapping share, you have to tap more. Find Andmade share in that list and tap it.  Then Andmads Share shows an even longer list of apps.  From there you have to scroll to find G+.  Not the simple, tap share tap G+ post.

Comment: If the list you get after clicking "More" is too long, it scrolls. Could it be that you simply need to scroll the list to see Google+? If that's not it, does Google+ still show up in the *app drawer* (the list of all apps)?

Comment: Also, instead of *Andmade*, take a look at [AppChooser](http://www.appbrain.com/app/appchooser/jp.co.noxi.apppicker). My personal preference. And besides: the "Photos" app is part of G+, afaik. Looks like they want to integrate the *Galery* app into G+ like they did the SMS with *Hangouts*.

Comment: It isn't in the More list.  I've scrolled.  It clearly was replaced by this Photos thing.